# Netty worker threads and throughput

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I created a netty server having serveral worker threads to check how the increase in the number of threads changes the throughput.
This is the code that I used. It is a slightly modified version of [Writing and echo server](https://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-8) that can be found in the Netty website.

EchoServerCompute

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

public class EchoServerCompute {

    private int port;

    public EchoServerCompute(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run(int threadCount) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(threadCount);
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                     ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoServerComputeHandler());
                 }
             })
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)          
             .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true); 

            ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync(); 

            f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 8080;
        new EchoServerCompute(port).run(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    }
}
```

EchoServerComputeHandler

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class EchoServerComputeHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) { 
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i=0; i<2000; i++)
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        ctx.write(msg);
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

I ran this server with 5 worker threads and then with 50 worker threads and used JMeter with 1000 users to test it. But the throughput that I received in both instances was almost the same.

I expected to see an increase in throughput when using more worker threads. So can someone please tell me if I am doing anything wrong here?

**EDIT**
The test environment where I am running this has 2 nodes designated as Server and Client. The Server node is running the netty program and the Client node is running JMeter. The server has an Intel Xeon 5160 CPU and 16GB RAM. The client has an Intel Xeon E5506 CPU and 8GB RAM. The link between them is 1Gbps.

Comment: Did you figure out the reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 6):

You are facing several issues here:

**Java is too smart**

```
for (int i=0; i<2000; i++)
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
```

The JIT will detect this as dead code and simply remove it completely. This means your code will complete in a fraction of a millisecond. To fix this add `result` to the response so it cannot be eliminated.

**Your hardware is limited**

More worker threads don't necessarily mean more throughput, as your machine actually needs to be able to handle the workload. If you also run JMeter on the same machine, you won't see any increase in throughput as early as with an amount of `threads >= amount_of_cpus / 2` Keep in mind that if you use an Intel CPU has hyper-cores that register as "real" CPUs, but won't do any work. So if you run this on an Intel Quad-Core, don't expect any increase in throughput after the 2nd worker thread.

**Threading takes time**

It actually takes time to manage the threads and switch between them. So after a certain amount of threads in the system your throughput will noticeably decline. Your stepping from 5 to 50 is too much to detect this, try to advance in steps of 2 threads.

**Threading is chaotic**

The order of execution with threads is undefined. So if you run enough threads, they will start to steal execution time from each other. Some might complete near instantly, while others will be put in line waiting for several seconds. At 50 threads you will see a much increased time to complete, simply because so many threads are constantly on hold. You can see this by comparing the min and max execution time, which should start to diverge with a growing number of threads.

Answer (score 3):

Netty is designed to support non-blocking I/O, which means the threads are not blocked. Switching from one thread to another has a cost, so a fixed number of threads is more efficient. This number is usually `number_of_core × 2`. Java's `Executor` is the right abstraction to distribute tasks among available threads.

Just think that once every core runs at full capacity, creating more threads won't help. Increasing the thread pool size above the number of physical threads available only helps in the case of blocking I/O to deal with more simultaneous connections.

If your tasks don't take too long you can run them in the same thread pool as the `EventLoopGroup`. Don't try to adjust the number of threads. Instead, adjust how the total amount of threads is allocated between I/O and tasks. You can use two separate `Executors` (the `EventLoopGroup` being one) or you can tune the value of [`EventLoopGroup#setIoRatio`](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoopGroup.html#setIoRatio-int-).

Answer (score 0):

Because of most http server have two limit of workthread.

One is the max count of worker thread for 'endpoint'.Another is the max count of worker thread for server.

Endpoint based on ip adderss (or session),the default max thread count for one endpoint is 5.So although you created 1000 user to test,but your 1000 user belong to one endpoint,so the max throughput always 5.

This limitation aims to slove one endpoint request server too much,this will cause no work therad to process others endpoint,this will be serious and dangerious.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

1. Remove the loop which does the multiplication and retest
2. Check your JMeter config. Could you please post your thread config?
3. What is the current Requests per second/throughput? And what is your system configuration? Might you you are reaching your system limitation.

Comment: 1. Any reason why you suggest removing the loop? Is it due to the reason @TwoThe mentioned? 
2. When you say JMeter config, is it the .properties file or the .jmx file of the test? 
3. The throughput that I get in both situations is about 17,000/sec. The test setup consists of 2 nodes designated as server and client. Server has an Intel Xeon 5160 CPU and 16GB RAM. The client has an Intel Xeon E5506 CPU and 8GB RAM. The link between them is 1Gbps